# How to traverse a list without losing elements

Tags: ocaml

so i have a function:

```
let rec add_rules start rules prod =
  match rules with
  | [] -> prod
  | nonterm::lst -> 
      if fst nonterm = start then 
        add_rules start (List.remove_assoc (fst nonterm) rules) (nonterm::prod)
      else if check_sym (fst nonterm) prod then 
        add_rules start (List.remove_assoc (fst nonterm) rules) (nonterm::prod)
      else 
        add_rules start lst prod
```

and it takes an element called `start`, a list of pairs called `rules` where `(x,[y])` and `x` is an element and `y` is a list, and an empty list `prod`.

without getting too much into detail about the specifics of this function, i basically want it to traverse the list of pairs (`rules`) and add certain elements to the empty list `prod`.

**problem:** in the first two if/else if statements, my code successfully removes the pair corresponding to `(fst nonterm)` and passes in the entire original list (minus `(fst nonterm)`) back to the recursive function. however, in the last else statement, i recursively traverse through the list by calling the tail of the original `rules` list, passing that in to the function, and therefore ending up unable to ever access those heads ever again.

is there any way i can avoid this? or is there any way i can traverse the list without getting rid of the head each time?

thank you in advance!!!

Comment: This doesn't look like Lisp, rather some ML variant.

Comment: Add a parameter?

Comment: Your question is unclear. First, by definition, "the entire original list minus `fst nonterm`" does not contain `nonterm`, i.e. the head of the list: even in the first two cases you pass (at best, assuming there's no duplicate in `rules`) the tail of the list to your recursive call. Second, traversing a list basically means taking the tail of the list until you end up with the empty list. As suggested, it is possible to add an extra parameter to `add_rules` that will remain constant through the successive calls, but you should explain a bit more the context in which you want to use `add_rules`

Comment: Why would you want to access the heads anyway? The purpose of recursive functions is to break a big problem into smaller ones. Also, I'm pretty sure that using `List.fold` would help you make your code easier to read and write.

Comment: `(List.remove_assoc (fst nonterm) rules)` is the same as `lst` so in all 3 cases you pass the same to the recursion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you need to introduce an extra parameter for that, as @coredump has suggested. 
So you will end up with an accumulator `prod` that will contain the result, that you're building, a queue of rules to be processed that reduces in size with each step of recursion (currently named `rules` in your version) and the `rules` that will contain all the rules (modulo those that you explicitly delete).